# Combine Query spoecific results in one row

Tags: php, mysql

I got a question regarding MySQL and finding the right query for it.

At the moment I got this query:

```
SELECT f.id
 , f.name 
 , e.name as exhibition_name
 , l.name as `language`
FROM `app_forms` f
LEFT JOIN  `app_exhibitions` e ON(f.id = e.form_id )
LEFT JOIN `app_forms_translations` ft ON(ft.form_id = f.id )
LEFT JOIN `app_languages` l ON(ft.lang_id = l.id)
```

This combines records from the following tables:

```
app_exhibitions
-id
-name
-location
-form_id

app_forms
-id
-name

app_form_translations
-id
-form_id
-lang_id
-content

app_languages
-id
-name
-code
```

But now I get multiple records if there are multiple forms for a single exhibition, which list forms double but with different exhibitions for each one of them. I want them to group up, so that I have a single row for every form I got but the exhibitions grouped up with concat.

I already tried this but than I get one record with every single exhibition name listed up in the exhibition column.

```
SELECT f.id
     , f.name 
     , group_concat(e.name separator ',') as exhibition name
     , l.name as `language`
FROM `app_forms` f
LEFT JOIN  `app_exhibitions` e ON(f.id = e.form_id )
LEFT JOIN `app_forms_translations` ft ON(ft.form_id = f.id )
LEFT JOIN `app_languages` l ON(ft.lang_id = l.id)
```

Comment: This query fails. Is the alias "exhiibition" [sic] or "name"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `group by`:

```
SELECT f.id,
       f.name,
       group_concat(e.name separator ',') as exhibition name,
       l.name as `language`
FROM `app_forms` f
LEFT JOIN  `app_exhibitions` e ON(f.id = e.form_id )
LEFT JOIN `app_forms_translations` ft ON(ft.form_id = f.id )
LEFT JOIN `app_languages` l ON(ft.lang_id = l.id)
GROUP BY f.id, f.name, l.name;
```